# How to bind width for different Grid so that they have same width for SL app?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

Suppose I have 2 Grid in a user control and I want these 2 grids have same width. So What I did is the xaml like:

```
 <Grid x:Name="BasicGrid"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  />
 <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="{Binding ElementName=BasicGrid, Path=Width}" >
```

but it looks like not working.
How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below code inside your user control.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid />
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

This will divide the top grid into two columns with same width.

Let me know if it works.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

have you try with

```
Width="{Binding ElementName=BasicGrid, Path=Width,Mode=TwoWay}"
```